# Can someone recommend some a font for a technology blog? Or atleast should it be serif ot sans-serif?

Tags: fonts, blog

I'm looking for fonts suggestions for a tech blog.
Should the font be serif or sans-serif?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Look at some tech blogs. What do they use? Use something similar.

Comment: @ZachSaucier That's my first thought, it seems almost all blogs use a sans-serif font. But I saw some use a serif which seemed weird to me, I also read that serif font makes you look trustworthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like Freight Sans, which Stratechery uses.